# react-router-dom and redux subapp: useNavigator causes redux reload

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm using react-router-dom v6. I'm versed with `redux` and `react` but only just starting to "go deep" with `react-router-dom`.

I have nested routes.  One of the "nests" has access to the redux `<Provider>` context.

Despite navigating **within** the "nest" of `Route`s with access to the redux context, all of the rendered components in the `Router` context are being re-rendered - and with it resetting redux.

Finally, there are several reasons for this design, but one of them is so that I can initialize the middleware for a given project (specified in the url).

```js
const middleware = (projectId) => {
  let initialized = false;
  return (store) => (next) => (action) => {
    if (!initialized) {
      initialized = true;
      next({ type: "SET_READY", projectId });
    }
    next(action);
  };
};
```

Here is a [link to the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-farrell-859dw7?file=/src/redux-store.js) that highlights the issue.

Comment: Do you mean `useNavigation`? It uses a react context under the hood. If, for example, you use it inside the `Projects` component it will rerender each time the location changed.

Comment: Are you saying that `ProjectView` is rerendering with routes change? Or that `SubApp` is? I find it a bit odd that `ProjectView` renders an `Outlet` *and* descendent routes, though it doesn't appear that `ProjectView` has any nested routes. What is `useNavigator? Do you mean the `useNavigate` hook? Can you provide a more complete and comprehensive [mcve]?

Comment: Re nesting: in my mental model `SubApp` “is a Route”.  `Routes` is how to construct nested routes from separate components. The `Outlet` is rendered by the parent `Route`, the route with the `SubApp` element.

Comment: The `Projects` Component re-renders was my first answer; but I suspect it is “its” `Outlet` that might be…

Comment: Using the `Routes` component within a rendered component creates ***descendent*** routes. ***Nested*** routes are `Route` components nested directly within another `Route` component and are rendered into an `Outlet` component of the parent route's component. It may be easier to understand the issue if you could provide us a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you.  I will look into the descendant vs nested point to better understand how that is causing extra reloading.  The good news is that it seems that the design is not flawed, but more my execution :))  Finally, my next step will be to create a codesandbox example.

Comment: @DrewReese I created a sandbox version of the issue.  The list of projects updates every time I click on an item in the list.  I suspect that has to do with the fact that the render includes `Outlet`.  What remains is the fact that redux keeps keeps sending a @INIT action with every click as described.

Comment: The `@INIT` action is dispatched a lot because every time the `ProjectDetail` component renders it creates a new Redux store object as an unintentional side-effect. Other than this I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with this code to even make a suggestion.

Comment: I solved part of the problem by memoizing the store; updates dependent on the projectId.

Comment: I did the same in your sandbox as well. Is/was the only issue the unstable Redux store reference (*exacerbated by the route navigation and component mounting/unmounting*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @DrewReese for engaging me on this issue.

In the sandboxed description of the issue, I solve the issue by memoizing the function that instantiates the store.  The middleware has a two-step initialization process: (1) set the project id (2) load the store.  The store value in the second step depends on what is returned by the server (i.e., if null, use a new store).

```js
// core-app.jsx

  // Three versions of the store instantiation process

  // 1. resets store on every new page within the project detail view (bad)
  // const storeWithProject = store(projectId);

  // 2. @@INIT instantiates using initialState where projectId = null (see reducer)
  // const storeWithProject = useMemo(() => store(projectId), [projectId]);

  // 3. The comprehensive solution
  const storeWithProject = useMemo(
    () => store(projectId, seedState(projectId)),
    [projectId]
  );
```

This all said, in the actual app, I *wasn't able* to get use the redux `<Provider>` within the `<BrowserRouter>` context.  I was not able to prevent a re-render of the `SubApp` component with every route change (as described above); my reliance on `useEffect` to fetch data (e.g., list of projects) at various points in the app is beyond my current skill-set :-/ (prop and state changes in context of react-router is tough-stuff to manage).

The solution that I'm working on now is to "raise" the redux provider to minimize the number of parents that might trigger a re-render. A somewhat disappointing conclusion because I can't leverage the "natural" entry point for when to instantiate the redux store.